# How to pass a structure to a c++ function and return the same with some modifications?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

I have following struct in my c++ function.

```
struct Cam
{
    char ip[16];
    char login[16];
    char pass[16];
    char name[16];
};
```

Following is the method I have exposed from my cpp class-

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Cam* AddCameraStruct1(Cam cam)
{
//modify the cam object
}
```

Here is how I am defining the struct and function in c#.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal unsafe struct Cam
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string ip;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string login;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string pass;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string name;
    }

 [DllImport(@"mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
    internal static extern IntPtr AddCameraStruct1(DPAPI.Cam*);
```

I am not getting how to consume this in c#.Please suggest if something is wrong.

```
unsafe
 {
                DPAPI.Cam cam = new DPAPI.Cam();
                cam.ip = "192.168.0.232";
                cam.login = "admin";
                cam.pass = "admin";
                cam.name = "kekekeke";
                DPAPI.Cam* cam1 = (DPAPI.Cam*)DPAPI.AddCameraStruct1(cam);
}
```

I am getting following errors -

Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does this mean : "I am not getting how to consume this in c#" ? What errors do you get?

Comment: please see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return structs from functions like you do, you can simply pass the struct by reference (this is how the whole Windows API is defined BTW).

Here is how to declare the struct, don't forget to indicate the charset is Ansi:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal struct Cam
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string ip;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string login;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string pass;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string name;
}
```

Here is how to declare the method (the ref argument is like using a *):

```
[DllImport(@"mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern void AddCameraStruct1(ref Cam pcam);
```

Here is how to declare it in C/C++:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void AddCameraStruct1(Cam *pcam)
{
  strcpy_s(pcam->name, "hello"); // for example
}
```

Here is how you would call it now:

```
var cam = new Cam();
cam.ip = "192.168.0.232";
cam.login = "admin";
cam.pass = "admin";
cam.name = "kekekeke";
AddCameraStruct1(ref cam);
// cam.name is now "hello"
```

Note you don't need to use the unsafe keyword at all in your code.

Comment: I tried the above with out keyword it worked fine.Any rules for when to use out instead of ref?

Comment: What if I need to modify the call to send a array of structures to native code?I understand this can be done by passing IntPtr to the array. NOt exactly sure how to do it.

Comment: Use ref is you are passing data in as well as out. Which is how it looked in your question. That's basic C# though. Read the docs on those two keywords.